# Using JQuery to Style form elements

Tags: jquery

I've seen jquery used to change a form select drop down box in to a 'pretty' drop down list widget.  I can't remember where I saw this but does anyone have any links or example code which show examples of how to use jquery to style form elements?  I'd prefer it if it was code rather than a built in plug in.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you crack open one of the plugins and look at its code?  This kind of styling is not trivial.  Telerik (and other vendors) have built a pretty good business doing this sort of thing so that programmers don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You might like [this](http://www.prismstudio.co.uk/2009/05/jquery-plugin-stylish-select-unobstrusive-select-box-replacement/) or [this](http://www.brainfault.com/2008/02/10/new-release-of-jquery-selectbox-replacement/) (smoother initial look) plugin.** Both plugins aim at unobtrusively replacing the default `<select>` box.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really style drop-downs. They're OS-level elements, not CSS elements. You can replace them with a combination of DIVs to emulate a drop-down, but styling on drop-downs themselves is rather limited.

Comment: conbination of UL LI sounds better! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try the **select box** replacement from filament group that support jquery ui theme roll!

> http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/

for **check boxes** try this:

> http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

for **other form elements** just use CSS and images!

Answer (score 0):

[jQtransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) is the best Plugin i found so far, This one is very easy to implement, and progressive enhanced.

This one also unobtrusively replaces the default `<select>` box.

Also Here is another one:  [uniform plugin](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/) this one has many options.