# Size of drop down box on select element

Tags: html, css, select

How do you set the size of the drop down box on a select element?
Not the select element itself but the drop down box part of it when you click for options?

```
______________
|____________| input box
|            |
|            |
|            |
|____________| size of drop down box containing options
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to change the size to increase the number of options displayed, use HTML like: `<select size="3" ...` .

But if you want to change the "pop-up" size, than as others have said, you can't do this with CSS.

The best workaround is to use one of the many jQuery plugins.  See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766594/)**.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done with a standard SELECT element. Support for styling SELECT and OPTION is very limited.

You can use a bit of scripting to replace the SELECT with an UL, that you can style perfectly. Checkout http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/ or http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect2/ for examples.

Comment: both links are dead!

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably. Some browsers may have a proprietary way to do it (but don't ask me what). Only option would be to create a custom drop down list control possibly using a drop down div similar to the way the jQuery autocomplete works, and not use a standard HTML SELECT.